# Converting Long Lat from Address in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, references

I want to convert Long Lat from Address using OpenLayers.

For example:

```
Address: London => Lat: 51.507351 , Long: 0.127758
```

I can't document tutorial.

Comment: When you have a coding question, it should include relevant part of the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geocoding

Answer (score -1):

Spatial libraries like open Layers or leaflet dons't support what you need (Geocoding) . 
Openlayers does not feature a Geocoding API. There are several questions here related to geocoding. Some of them specifically mention openlayers and geocoding (many do so with Google; google has a good api for geocoding named nominatim). Leaflet also have plugin for this question you can find it on github.
But due the country that you want to geocoding any plugin has diffrent quality.
If you want have you'r geocoding algorithym you must use Topologic rules like buffer or intersection integration with network analysis ,that's a liitle hard !